# Unofficial app store to install ipa with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, installation, ipa

I am new to flutter and want to know how to implement a little app store for iOS with flutter.
I am working flutter but no idea to install app without app store.

Comment: Yes, it is possibile. Search for "Over The Air" (OTA) distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is that you can have initially you can have the debug build for the iOS directly run in the debug mode which will only work on that device.  And if you want to have it for the many people then you can use the Visual studio Appcenter where you want to have the apple certificate to be installed and you need to have a udid of all apple device you want the application to run.

Check out this link : https://medium.com/@arup.nayak/hosting-enterprise-ios-apps-with-appcenter-without-mdm-ca2f0b234686

Comment: Is it still working? I try it but after installing app, app not launch and say "App needs to be updated"